# Error consulta Cakephp3 NOT

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que me devuelva los usuarios con un nombre que no tengan una id que este dentro de un array que tengo almacenado los que ya estan.

```
$usuarios = $this->Usuarios->find('all',['contains'=>'centros'])
 ->where([
     'Usuarios.nombre' =>$this->request->getData('nombre'),
     'centro_id' => $this->request->getData('centroid'),
     'Usuarios.id NOT' => $this->request->getData('lista') ])
 ->toArray();
```

Tambien he probado así.

```
$usuarios = $this->Usuarios->find('all',[
  'contains'=>'centros',
  'conditions' =>['Usuarios.id NOT' =>$this->request->getData('lista')]])
->where([
    'Usuarios.nombre' =>$this->request->getData('nombre'),
    'centro_id' => $this->request->getData('centroid')])
->toArray();
```

El array es el siguiente ['5','9','22'] y esta en el dato lista.

Pero al hacer la consulta me devuelve Cannot convert value of type `array` to integer

No se si mi fallo está en como planteo la consulta de NOT
A parte me gustaria que el nombre busque coincidencias es decir yo le paso el nombre María pero quiero que me devuelva las que se llamen María Navarro